# Implicit type with struct of slices

Tags: go, struct, types, slice

If I have a file like this:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type Language struct {
   Example []string
   Link []string
}

func main() {
   o := Language{
      {".go", "go.ps1"},
      {"golang.org", "go.dev"},
   }
   fmt.Println(o)
}
```

I get this result:

```
missing type in composite literal
```

I found I can resolve like this:

```
[]string{".go", "go.ps1"},
[]string{"golang.org", "go.dev"},
```

but is that strictly required? I would think Go would know the type of each
property based on the `struct` definition.

Comment: Yes, it's required, exactly as the error states. Go often does not infer things or allow ambiguous syntax. It favors the compiler being incredibly fast to the code being short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is not that the compiler doesn't know the type, it is that the syntax for a composite literal requires the type:

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals

A string array literal is `[]string{"a","b",","c"}`, not `{"a","b","c"}`.

Answer (score 1):

You need field in struct definition, like this

```
o := Language{
    Example: []string{".go", "go.ps1"},
    Link:    []string{"golang.org", "go.dev"},
}
fmt.Println(o)
```